# Handle buttons dropdowns created dynamically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have created few buttons and dropdowns dynamically. Code compiles fine but My event handlers are not firing? How should I handle this situation?

```
Protected Sub CreateAndLoadDropdowns()
       Dim ddlBureauDropdowns As New DropDownList
        Dim btnGo As New Button         
         With btnGo
            .Text = "Go"
            .ID = tempList2(0).MenuID
        End With       
        AddHandler btnGo.Click, AddressOf Me.btnGo_Click
        AddHandler ddlBureauDropdowns.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf Me.ddlBureauDropdowns_SelectedIndexChanged
        phAddDropdnsHere.Controls.Add(ddlBureauDropdowns)        
        phAddDropdnsHere.Controls.Add(btnGo)           
    Next
End Sub
```

Protected Sub btnGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  End Sub

Protected Sub ddlBureauDropdowns_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  End Sub

Comment: With those changes the Button Click Event Handler works just fine for me.  It is your DropDownList's SelectedIndexChanged Event Handler that wouldn't work due to your AddHandler statement pointing to "ddlBureauDropdowns_SelectedIndexChanged" instead of "ddlBureau_SelectedIndexChanged" that is defined below the first code snippet.

Comment: Thank you. That was a typing mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have moved the code to Page_init and added autopostback = true for the dropdown. The Event handlers are firing now.